# using toString()

Tags: java, android

I am developing a simple android dice game, where 2 players take turns to roll, if you get doubles you win. I am trying to use toString to output to a toast which player wins when it lands on doubles.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
private Button rollDice;
int player = 1;
private ImageView dice1, dice2;
TextView display;
boolean rolling = false;

@NonNull
public String toString(){
    return String.valueOf(player);
}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rollDice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rollDice);
    dice1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dice1);
    dice2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dice2);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
```

followed by my onclick method with random.nextInt and my switch cases.

Then I call the toString in the toast:

```
                if (d1 == d2){

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                String text = "Player " + toString() + " wins!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

            }

            if (player == 1){

                player = 2;
            }
            else{
                player = 1;
            }
```

It then outputs "Player com.ellis.newdice.MainActivity$1 *then random numbers* wins"

Am I using the toString method incorrectly or is it the int player not being used properly?

Comment: Use `String text =  "Player " + player+ " wins!"`.

Comment: Thank you, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

`player` is an `int`, so in this case you don't need a `toString` method:

```
String text = "Player " + player + " wins!";
```

Also, delete the `public String toString()` method because you might have problems with the default `Activity.toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The way you use it, the `toString()` method of your activity class is invoked, 
this is why you see `com.ellis.newdice.MainActivity$1`. 
You don't need `toString()` to achieve what you want. 
Use this:

```
String text = "Player " + winner + " wins!";
```

Change `winner` with the variable (integer?) you use in your code for the winning player.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
String text = "Player " + String.valueOf(player) + " wins";
```

The toString method is unnecessary. String.valueOf(int number) will take your integer value (the player that wins) and convert it to a String which can be displayed in your Toast.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the object you call this from is not actually your `MainActivity` but some Anonymous inner class inside of it, likely some listener. You might have to replace the call with `MainActivity.this.toString()` to make explicit which `toString()` you want to call.

More generally `toString()` is not a method that's called explicitly generally. It's very useful when you get it called by other code for you. For example `String s = "foo " + something` will implicitly call `toString()` on `something` (provided it's an object and not already a `String`).

Answer (score -1):

You should not call any custom function as `toString()` as it is a reserved function name part of the superclass `Object` in Java. I'm pretty sure it will cause conflicts between your function and the `Object.toString()` one.

You could try to:

1. Rename your function (try `playerAsString()`)
2. Call the function with a `this`: `this.toString()` to be sure you call the function from your class.

Comment: `toString()` is not a "reserved function name", such a thing doesn't exist in Java. It's simply a method that exists on `java.lang.Object` and calling it like that is perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Not what I meant by 'reserved function name', in my opinion it is a bad habit to use this name without any will to @Override it. If it were forbidden, compiler would tell us. Still, the `com.ellis.newdice.MainActivity$1` might come from the MainActivity.toString() method, so it's not the correct toString() which is called, right?